# Multiple APK's how does Play decide which to download

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-manifest

I am going to create a tablet APK, which will not have some functionality that my phone APK has.. that's basically the only difference, however since the tablet APK will have less permissions (no phone requirements) how do I make sure folks with PHONES are going to get the PHONE version of the APK?

IE, a table user will only get the version with no phone permissions, since their device doesn't support it, that I get.

But a phone user, could run the APK without the phone requirements, as well as the APK with the phone requirements, so how do I make sure that phone users get the PHONE version of the APK, using the multiple APK setup in Play?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the ["compatible-screens"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) tag for the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how reliable this is, with phone screens continuing to get gargantuan, but I think this will work.